# How to do it right : embedding a png directory to an android project and reffering to its items

Tags: android

what i did was that i added a directory named Images, which is full of png files to src\ (so all the images are in src\Images
and then reffered to it in code like this:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Images\\"+i+".png");
```

it didnt work, how can it be done correctly?

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the images?

Comment: read them as bitmaps and draw them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the images to the appropriate version of `res/drawable-*/`, based on density, then reference it a `R.drawable.basename` (for an image named `basename.png`) for places where you need them (e.g., `setImageResource()` on an `ImageView`).

Comment: so there is no way to include png files in an android project and read them programmatically to Bitmaps using their absoulote path? in my humble eyes it seems like the drawable approach is somewhat tedious and a workaround, cause what im trying to do suppose to be straight forward. (as it is in Java projects)

Comment: @OfekRon: Normally, Android developers care about screen density, in which case using the resource system is rather useful. And, there are cases where using the `Drawable` abstraction can be important (e.g., using different drawables in different states). You are welcome to package the images in your project's `assets/` directory and use the combination of `AssetManager` and `BitmapFactory`, though that would be rather unusual. But ignoring screen density because you find it to be "somewhat tedious" is an exceedingly bad idea.

Comment: It's not all that unusual if they're not UI assets. If it's something like a folder of photographs, then having it in the assets folder is probably the best route. Agreed on your last edit, though -- you shouldn't do this just to avoid using drawables where you should be.

Comment: @kcoppock: "If it's something like a folder of photographs" -- I'd consider that to be rather unusual, in the grand scheme of things. But you are certainly correct, that there will be cases when images are better off in assets (or perhaps raw resources).

Comment: is there an helper class dealing with scaling drawbles?

Comment: @OfekRon: In general, drawables are scaled as a part of drawing them (e.g., `ImageView` knows how to scale). If you are drawing to the `Canvas` directly yourself, there may be helper code for assisting with the scaling, but I do not do much `Canvas` work and therefore do not know what such helper code would be. Sorry!